# Melhor desempenho em um sistema em WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desempenho

Como deixar um sistema em alta performance?

Seguir um padrão de projetos MVVM?

Eu tenho o seguinte XAML, mas quando eu executo ele trava na hora de passar o foco para outros `textBox`. Por que?

O meu sistema fica muito lento, não estou entendendo o porque.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Curriculos_3_Camadas.View.EmpresaView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
         xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Width="auto" Height="auto" Background="White" d:DesignWidth="1232.5" d:DesignHeight="853">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,77">


    <!-- L I N H A    U M -->
    <TextBlock Text="Código:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,17,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="textEmpCodigo" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Width="170" Margin="196,15,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Text="F2" Margin="371,18,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelUltimoCodigoEmpresa" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Margin="390,18,0,0" Width="177"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbEmpresaInativa" Content="Empresa Inativa" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Margin="600,17,0,0" />

    <TextBlock Text="CNPJ / CPF:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Margin="130,43,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="textEmpCnpjCpf" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Width="170" Margin="196,40,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Data de Abertura:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Margin="390,43,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="labelDataAbertura" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Margin="489,43,0,0" Width="111"/>

    <TextBlock Text="Razão Social / Nome:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Margin="79,67,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="textEmpRSNome" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Width="560" Margin="196,65,0,0"/>

    <!-- L I N H A    D O I S -->
    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1900" Height="25" Fill="#E8E8E8" Margin="0,115,-668,0"/>

    <TabControl Name="tabControl" Margin="150,115,0,38">

        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Grid Name="Panel">
                                <Border 
                             Name="Border"
                             BorderBrush="#A9A9A9" 
                             BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" 
                             CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                             MinWidth="120">
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="white" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#E8E8E8" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabItem Name="tiDadosGeraisEmpresas" Header="Dados Gerais" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" IsSelected="True" Margin="70,0,-80,-5" TabIndex="-67">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="-72,0,2,-13">
                <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Height="655">

                    <TextBlock Text="Nome Fantasia:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="26" Canvas.Top="17"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpNomeFantasia" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="290" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="15"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Contato:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="448" Canvas.Top="17"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpContato" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="240" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="498" Canvas.Top="15"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Site:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="784" Canvas.Top="17"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpSite" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="240" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="811" Canvas.Top="15"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="CEP:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="85" Canvas.Top="43"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpCep" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="40"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Código IBGE:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="329" Canvas.Top="43"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpCodigoIbge" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="403" Canvas.Top="40"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="F2" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Canvas.Left="568" Canvas.Top="43"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Município:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="343" Canvas.Top="93"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpMunicipio" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="210" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="403" Canvas.Top="90"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Bairro:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="93"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpBairro" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="90"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Estado (UF):" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="628" Canvas.Top="93"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpUf" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="696" Canvas.Top="90"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Tipo de Logradouro:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="68"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpTipoLogradouro" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="65"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Logradouro:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="333" Canvas.Top="68"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpLogradouro" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="210" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="403" Canvas.Top="65"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Número:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="644" Canvas.Top="68"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpNumero" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="115" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="696" Canvas.Top="65"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Complemento:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="853" Canvas.Top="63"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpComplemento" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="115" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="936" Canvas.Top="60"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Inscrição Estadual:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="118" Canvas.Left="12"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpInscEst" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="115"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Cód. Serv.:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="393" Canvas.Top="118"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpCodServ" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="453" Canvas.Top="115"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Cód. Ativ.:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="638" Canvas.Top="118"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpCodAtiv" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="355" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="696" Canvas.Top="115"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Inscrição Municipal:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="143" Canvas.Left="4"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpInscMun" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="140"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Regime Trib.:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="379" Canvas.Top="143"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpRegTrib" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="598" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="453" Canvas.Top="140"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="RNTRC:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="168" Canvas.Left="68"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpRntrc" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="190" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="165"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Tipo de Empresa:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="357" Canvas.Top="168"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpTipoEmpresa" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="598" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="453" Canvas.Top="165"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="CNAE - Classificação Nacional de Atividades Econômicas" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="195"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Código:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="219" Canvas.Left="68"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpCodigoCnae" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="216"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Descrição:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="243" Canvas.Top="219"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpDescCnae" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="644" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="302" Canvas.Top="216" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                    <Button Name="btnAdicionarCnae" Content="Adicionar" Width="100" Canvas.Left="951" Canvas.Top="214" FontWeight="Bold" TabIndex="-76"/>
                    <DataGrid Name="dataGridCnae" Height="100" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="243" Width="938" FontWeight="Normal" IsReadOnly="True"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="All">

                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=codigo}" Header="Código" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=descricao}" Header="Descrição" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>

                    <TextBlock Text="Contatos" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="354"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="E-mail:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="378" Canvas.Left="68"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="348" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="375"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Observações:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="485" Canvas.Top="378"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpObs1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="386" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="560" Canvas.Top="375" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                    <Button Name="btnAdicionarEmails" Content="Adicionar" Width="100" Canvas.Left="951" Canvas.Top="372" FontWeight="Bold" TabIndex="-73"/>
                    <DataGrid Name="dataGridEmails" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100"
                              Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="414" Width="937" FontWeight="Normal" IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="All">

                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=email}" Header="E-mail (s)" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=obs}" Header="Observação" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>

                    <TextBlock Text="Prefixo (99):" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Top="520" Canvas.Left="46"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpPrefixo" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="517"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Telefones:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="243" Canvas.Top="520"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpTelefones" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="302" Canvas.Top="517"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Observações:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Canvas.Left="485" Canvas.Top="520"/>
                    <TextBox Name="textEmpObs2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="386" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Canvas.Left="560" Canvas.Top="517"/>
                    <Button Name="btnAdicionarTelefones" Content="Adicionar" Width="100" Canvas.Left="951" Canvas.Top="515" FontWeight="Bold" TabIndex="-69"/>

                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGridTelefones" Height="100" Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="557"
                              Width="937" FontWeight="Normal" GridLinesVisibility="All" IsReadOnly="True">

                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <!-- <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id_empresa}" Header="Código" /> -->
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=prefixo}" Header="Prefixo2" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=telefone}" Header="Telefone2" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=obs}" Header="Observação2" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </DataGrid>

                </Canvas>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>

    <WindowsFormsHost VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="wfhSample" Grid.Row="0" Height="50" Width="186" Margin="862,10,0,0">
        <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
            <wf:PictureBox x:Name="picLetras"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    <Image x:Name="imgCarregaCaptcha" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="1051,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17" />
    <TextBlock Name="labelCaptcha" Text="Digite os caracteres acima e pressione Enter:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Red" Margin="862,65,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="textCaracteres" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="22" Height="15" Width="260" Margin="862,86,0,0"/>

    <Rectangle Fill="#E8E8E8" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,-2" />
    <Button x:Name="btnSalvarEmpresa" Content="Salvar (F9)" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Margin="198,0,0,2"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta é um tanto ampla, não tem um problema específico mas vou tentar ajudar, ainda que de forma genérica.

O WPF realmente tem uma série de detalhes que se não forem observados gerará problemas de performance. O mecanismo é complexo e não é fácil entender todas implicações. Além disto os *defaults* não são ideias para gerar boa performance.

Eu não possuo conhecimento específico mas existe bastante material sobre o assunto, vou listar alguns. Você precisará ler todas, procurar novas fontes, estudar muito o assunto e perfilar bastante até chegar em um bom resultado.

A primeira coisa que precisa conhecer é a [ferramenta de análise de performance do WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa969767(v=vs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Outra ferramenta](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html).

[Esse artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784529/Solutions-for-WPF-Performance-Issue) começa dar uma boa explicação sobre o problema.

[Aqui tem dicas](http://pelebyte.net/blog/2011/07/11/twelve-ways-to-improve-wpf-performance/) para melhorar a performance.

[Outras maneiras](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_wpf/article.php/c18025/10-Ways-to-Improve-the-Performance-of-Your-WPF-Application.htm) que ajudam melhorar a performance.

[Mais uma lista de dicas](http://www.wpftutorial.net/10PerformanceTips.html).

Considerações importantes de como [melhorar a inicialização](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/application-startup-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Um dos [artigos que mais gosto](http://kynosarges.org/WpfPerformance.html) sobre o assunto.

Mais um [artigo interessante](https://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/).

O fato de usar o MVVM não ajuda nada, pode até atrapalhar em alguns casos, mas nada significativo. Claro que se usar um padrão ruim ou fizer sem padrão algum pode atrapalhar.

Comment: Mto obrigado bigown